How to derive GEE from GLM?
I am now reading the lecture note from:
https://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~kshedden/Courses/Regression_Notes/gee.pdf


Why do we have $V_{i}^{-1}(y_{i}-\mu_{i})$? I cannot link the last equation on page 4 to the last equation on page 5.
